# jQuery: Multi image dimension validation before upload

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to valdiate a multiple image upload using jQuery. The validation proccess get the images dimensions and check if it is greater than  338x450. But I know very little about javascript. Can someone help me? Here's the code I'm trying:

**HTML:**

```html
<input class="form-control" id="ads-photos" name="ads-photos[]" type="file" accept="image/jpeg, image/jpg" multiple />
```

**javascript**

```js
var isFilesOk;

$('#ads-photos').change(function (evt) {
    validateDimensions();

}); 

function validateDimensions() {
    var fi = document.getElementById('ads-photos');
    if (fi.files.length > 0) {      
      for (var i = 0; i <= fi.files.length - 1; i++) {
          var fileName, fileExtension, fileSize, fileType, dateModified;
          fileName = fi.files.item(i).name;
          fileExtension = fileName.replace(/^.*\./, '');
          if (fileExtension == 'jpg' || fileExtension == 'jpeg') {
             if (readImageFile(fi.files.item(i))) {
                 alert(isFilesOk);
             } else {
                alert(isFilesOk);
             }            
            }
        }
    }
    // GET THE IMAGE WIDTH AND HEIGHT USING fileReader() API.
    function readImageFile(file) {
        var reader = new FileReader(); // CREATE AN NEW INSTANCE.
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            var img = new Image();      
            img.src = e.target.result;

            img.onload = function () {
                var w = this.width;
                var h = this.height;
                if (this.width >= 338 && this.height >= 450) {
                    isFilesOk = true;
                } else {
                     isFilesOk = false;
                }
            }
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        return isFilesOk;
    }
}
```

[A example link](https://codepen.io/boninho/pen/oNxjdXK)

The above code needs analyze all the images sended by the user to know if they all have minimum required dimensions. But I'm not getting it to work.

Comment: What is not happening with the code that you are expecting to happen or what is the error?

Comment: Hello @imvain2! When loading images, the first alert displays "undefined". I need that the script to analyze all the images sended by the user to know if they all have minimum required dimensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that the `readImageFile` method is asynchronous. The work it's doing happens *later*, after it's executed when the `onload` event is triggered on the file.

The best solution will depend a little on the environment you're targeting (eg: whether you need to support old IE, etc), but if you're able to use modern JS with Promises, this will be easier.

Basically, for each file that's selected, you want to get a Promise indicating whether the file is okay or not. A good way to do this is `map` the array to an array of Promises and use `Promise.all` to get a callback when they're all done.

Here's the method to get that for a single file:

```
function fileIsValid(file) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    var reader = new FileReader(); // CREATE AN NEW INSTANCE.
    reader.onload = function (e) {
      var img = new Image();      
      img.src = e.target.result;

      img.onload = function () {
        var w = this.width;
        var h = this.height;
        const isValid = w >= 338 && h >= 450;
        resolve(isValid);
      };
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  });
}
```

And then using this method:

```
const fi = document.getElementById('ads-photos');
const promises = [];
for (let i = 0; i <= fi.files.length - 1; i++) {
  const file = fi.files.item(i);
  if (/\.jpe?g$/.test(file.name)) {
    promises.push(fileIsValid(file));
  }
}
Promise.all(promises).then((results) => {
  // results is an array of booleans
  const allValid = results.every(Boolean);
  if (allValid) {
    alert('Yeah!');
  } else {
    alert('Nope');
  }
});
```

There's a few things to note here:

- you could make it shortcut once a single error is found by making the promise reject if it's invalid, and `Promise.all` then won't wait for any other pending promises. This is a bit of a style question about whether failed validation should result in a rejected promise. Up to you on that. In this case, it's reading from a local file system and I presume they'll be selecting a relatively small number of files, so short-circuiting probably won't make any noticeable difference.
- it doesn't handle *actual* errors (eg: what if a file is unable to be loaded?).

Comment: Thank'u @nickf. Works great!